# question: terraform accessing a bucket from another account to send data

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

so this is a theoretical question. I honestly do not even know where to start on this terrafrom coding adventure in regards to sending my logs a centralized account.

I have a s3 bucket called: mysecuritybucket in account1

I have 8 AWS accounts as of now in my organization. I plan to send data from account2-8 to account1's  s3 bucket so we can centralize logs of all sorts and other stuff. flow-logs may be one of the first i try it for.

within the same account, no problem, that is not too complicated to come up with a module and send that accounts logs to that same accounts s3 bucket.

I just do not know what pieces are involved to allow account2-8 to access the s3 bucket: mysecuritybucket so it can drop its logs there.

I have been trying to query the web, but i do not think my querying skills are working. i cant find any good examples/explanations.

Comment: Is there a way to make an existing s3 bucket that was built outside of terraform to be managed by terraform? That way I can add new accounts to the s3 policy when ever we have new account  come online? I guess as of now I would have to manually update the policy for this non terraform managed s3 bucket than I can point my logs to it once I give the new account access. In an ideal situation I could update the existing s3 buckets policy within terraform first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not that complicated. You basically need a [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html) in Acc1 which will **allow other accounts to upload objects** to it. The procedure is same, whether you use terraform or not. The general resources regarding such bucket policies are:

- [How can I grant a user in another AWS account the access to upload objects to my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-cross-account-upload-access/)
- [Step 1.3: Attach a bucket policy to grant cross-account permissions to account b](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html#access-policies-walkthrough-cross-account-permissions-acctA-tasks)
- [How can I provide cross-account access to objects that are in Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)

Once the bucket policy is in place, the **IAM roles or users in the other accounts** need to be modified as well to allow writing to the bucket in Acc 1. Info about his is also in the above links.

The only thing that can be not so straight forward is if you want the bucket to be **encrypted or not with KMS**. If you use encryption, then KMS policies also need to be modified to allow other accounts to use CMK form Acc 1:

- [Allowing users in other accounts to use a CMK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-modifying-external-accounts.html)
- [Share Custom Encryption Keys More Securely Between Accounts by Using AWS Key Management Service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/share-custom-encryption-keys-more-securely-between-accounts-by-using-aws-key-management-service/)